# In MATLAB, how do I find the coordinate position of the highest point in the gap under all these curves?

Tags: matlab, loops, max, shapes, curve

I have the below figure with 64 individual curves plotted. There is a vertical threshold over which these curves need to be. The width of the space over this threshold is shown as the DoF and is positioned by those two vertical lines, which can be anywhere the most central parts of the curves intersect with the threshhold.

My question is how do I determine the highest point of the area between the vertical lines and above the threshold but below all the curves? This might not coincide with an intersection.

The curves do not have the same domain (meaning their X values are not aligned).

The only way I can think of, which is really clunky, is to loop through x values from left to right, interrogate each curve by interpolating a point at that x value, getting the minimum of all those values, and moving to the next x. That builds a list of minimum values, and then I choose the maximum value of those minimums.

Is there are more clever way to do this? Can I do this with the plotted data? It's almost like I want to build a shape and then find the maximum y value of that shape.

[image: Figure with 64 curves and spec. lines]

Comment: The steps you describe in the question seem to be the most straightforward option, and would probably be rather fast when vectorized.

Comment: What you suggest sounds about right to me. I would use `interp1` to interpolate all curves into a common x-axis, then compute the min over those as Adriaan suggested. This way you don’t need to (explicitly) loop over x. Note that this is computationally cheaper than plotting the lines. :)

Comment: Do you have the functional representation of all curves? i.e. not only numerics. In that case you can quite easily find the intersections of all curves, get the lowest above the threshold, and then find the x-span

Comment: If your sure that the innermost two lines are the ones intersecting, you can find the biggest gap in x along the threshold, the sides of it identifying the two lines required. Then you only need to find a single intersection of the corresponding lines.

Comment: @gnovice Thanks, how would you envision the vectorizing to happen?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the idea. That seems a straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @Adriaan I can't be sure of any lines intersecting at all or even if they do that it would be the peak, so I need a general solution. I do have the polynomial coeffecients of the curve, but I'm not looking for intersections. Mainly just the highest point under all the curves, intersection or not.

Comment: if you have access to the plot itself, it's even easier to just poll the graphic first by running through your x values and just looking "up" until you see "not background colour". This gets you the same information without needing to evaluate any of your curves.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is what I was wondering. I do have access to the plot. How would I go about this?

Comment: You'd probably treat it as an image, and then use https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixel.html commands to check colors.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the tip. I tried it and it's not as robust as working with the raw data, cause it depends on image resolution and not having any other colors get in the way... but it's very interesting. Thanks for bringing that function to my attention!

Comment: In graphics it's called a scanline algorithm, so I don't know if someone wrote a nice little matlab package for that, but if they have, that's probably the term to search with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the numerical approach where I would recreate the individual curves within the same domain and using the same increments. This could be done with interpolation where:

```
newCurve = interp1(origXvalues, origYvalues, newXvalues)
```

But I have the polynomial coefficients of the curves I use so I just re-evaluated the polynomial over the bounded domain and used a very small increment:

```
% X domain of interest
minX;
maxX;

% Nx1 Cell array where rows are curve data (polynomial coefficients in this case)
cellArray;

% Pre-populate matrix where columns are curves
matCurves = []; 

% Hi-res domain values
newDomain = linspace(minX, maxX, 10000)'; 

% Cycle through curve sets
for jj = 1:size(cellArray, 1) 
    % Generate curve based on polynomials bounded within domain
    matCurves(:, jj) = polyval(cellArray{jj}, newDomain); 
    % Or to use interpolation if cellArray had X and Y values as columns
    % matCurves(:, jj) = interp1(cellArray{jj, 1}, cellArray{jj, 2}, newDomain);
end

% Find global max of the min of each domain increment
[minValues, idx] = max(min(matCurves, [], 2)); 

% Path that traces the lowest values within the domain
minValues; 

% X value of maximum point below all curves within domain
newDomain(idx);
```

This worked great for me and is really fast. Looping to generate the new curves with `polyval` or `interp1` is what takes the longest but in total for my data set of 68 curves and generating new curves with 10000 points, start to finish only took 0.06 seconds on my 7th-gen Core i7 laptop.

UPDATE: *Related question and solution but not appropriate for me. Adding it for completeness and others who pass this way.*

On the [Mathworks forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/411357-how-to-plot-the-highest-y-values-for-each-x-value-for-a-figure-with-multiple-plots#answer_329674) someone posted this code to mark out the path of the maximum of all the plots on a curve. To do the minimum, change max to min:

```
f=figure;hold on;
plot(rand(10,3))
a=f.Children;
L=a.Children;
D={L.YData};
E=cell2mat(D');
plot(L(1).XData,max(E),'r')
```

This is very clever. Looking at it, it doesn't quite work with my data set, because it requires that the curves already be of the same X domain, which mine are not. Also my curves are in groups in graphics containers so it's a little harder to get access to them compared to how that answer does with just 2 Children calls. Regarding the different domain, notice how this doesn't produce the minimum path:

```
f=figure;hold on;
plot(sort(rand(10,1)),rand(10,1),'b',sort(rand(10,1)),rand(10,1),'g',sort(rand(10,1)),rand(10,1),'k')
a=f.Children;
L=a.Children;
D={L.YData};
E=cell2mat(D');
plot(L(1).XData,min(E),'r'
```

Anyway, that's all for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

If your curves, while not aligned, take values on the same `x` lattice (i.e. the coordinates can only take the same discretised values within the DoF for all curves), then there is a "simpler" solution which doesn't involve interpolation.

For simplicity of notation, I assume your curves are given as a `1xn` struct-array `C` with fields `x` and `y` (where `n` is the number of curves), such that `C(k).x(i)` is the `i`th coordinate of the `k`th curve:

```
C = 
  1xn struct array with fields:

    x
    y
```

Different curves can have different number of points (i.e. `C(k).x` and `C(p).x` can have different sizes), and they may not be aligned. That being said, if the curves don't take values on the same `x` lattice, then they need to be [resampled](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) to a common one, at least within the bounds of the "DoF" (or less precisely using interpolation as you did).

Then, denoting `Dmin, Dmax` the lower and upper bounds of the "DoF", you can obtain the point shown in red with the min-max approach you proposed:

```
V = cell(1,n);
for k = 1:n
    xk = C(k).x;
    V{k} = C(k).y(  Dmin <= xk  &  xk <= Dmax  );
        % extract those y-values within the DoF
end

% concatenate as a matrix with n rows
V = vertcat(V{:}); 

max(min(V)) % voila!
```